# Gitlab always shows "No container image repositories in Container Registry for this project."

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, gitlab-ci-runner

I have configured a private registry at https://registry.domain.com

The only configuration I have changed in `gitlab.rb` is **registry_external_url**.

I have configured my tls certs and I am using a basic auth.

I have successfully pushed to my server during a CI but I keep having this message when I go on the registry page :

```
No container image repositories in Container Registry for this project
```

There are suggested command, does it matter to use the same suggested image name ?

I think Gitlab needs a way to authenticate to the server.

Comment: did you activate docker registry globaly and on project level?

Comment: I have activated both, globaly and at project level. I only configured the `registry_external_url` and the TLS certs. I have opened an issue on [gitlab-ce](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/32990#note_31031815) and I think it is because the registry **MUST** be on the same intranet.